# PHP/MySQL - Email validation not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this has been asked a lot, and I've search and literally tried it all. I'm really close, but can't get it to work.

I'm trying to check if the username or usermail is already in use and display the error accordingly.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {

    try 
    {
        $checkValidity = $connect->prepare('SELECT username, usermail FROM users WHERE username = :username OR usermail = :usermail');
        $checkValidity->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $checkValidity->bindValue(':usermail', $usermail);
        $checkValidity->execute();
        $row = $checkValidity->fetchColumn();

        if ($row == $username) {
            $errName = 'This username is already taken.';
        } 
        if ($row == $usermail) {
            $errMail = 'Email already in use.';
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        // print $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

It works fine for the username, but for the life of me I can't get the email error to work...

I attempted separate SELECT queries (username/usermail), and the email error would show ONLY if the username error showed.

The email error will never show just by itself.

I've spent one too many hours just trying to get this to work, and I'm slowly losing my mind.

Any indication would be **greatly** appreciated...!

Thank you...

Comment: use fetchRow if ($row['username'] == $username) { } if ($row['useremail'] == $usermail) { }

Comment: I don't use PDO a lot, but doesn't fetchColumn only retrieve the first column, which in your result set will ALWAYS be the username column?

Comment: you need to call `fetchColumn` again after `username` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FetchColumn return first column value. You need to use fetch instead. Like

```
$row = $checkValidity->fetch();
if ($row['username'] == $username) {
    $errName = 'This username is already taken.';
} 
if ($row['usermail'] == $usermail) {
    $errMail = 'Email already in use.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... This indeed did the trick! Works like a charm now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> There is no way to return another column from the same row if you use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve data.

your fetching username only you need to use fetch() to get the whole row and compare like this

```
$row = $checkValidity->fetch();

 if ($row['username'] == $username)  {
    $errName = 'This username is already taken.';
} 
 if ($row['useremail'] == $useremail)  {
    $errMail = 'Email already in use.';
}
```

Comment: Hah! I hadn't seen your edited message! Yes, that's the solution, it works! Thank you for taking the time to help.